# Passing a Sympy expression to Scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, numerical-methods

I am trying to optimize the following function

```
fun=-300.49858410695*C_0 - 301*C_1 - 60.2000000000003*C_2
```

But when I pass this expression to the scipy.optimize.minimize function I am getting errors.

```
TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

Here is the whole code that I have tried

```
x0=[1,1,1]
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun,x0,method="Nelder-Mead")
```

I understand that the problem lies with passing sympy expressions as function but is there any way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function out of your expression by *lambdifying* it.

```py
from sympy import lambdify
fun = lambdify( (C_0,C_1,C_2), fun))
...
```

Comment: TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'C_1' and 'C_0'

Comment: Can I see more of your code? The definitions of `C_0` to `C_2` for instance.

Comment: list_of_coefficinets=[Symbol("C_"+str(i)) for i in range(int(value))]

Comment: ff=lambdify(("C_0","C_1","C_2"),EL_c)

Comment: x0=[1,1,1]
scipy.optimize.minimize(ff,x0,method="Nelder-Mead")

Comment: I am able to evaluate the value of fun when i use
    fun.subs("C_0":1,"C_1":1,"C_2":1) for example